# Multiple comparison operators for one variable?

Tags: php

I need to do multiple checks for a variable. I've seen an "Equals" example, here: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp).
But they are two different variables. Right now I have:

```
if ($color == 'blue')
{
//do something
}
```

But I need to to multiple checks for $color. Eg if it equals red or green too. How is this written?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As simple as:

```
if ($color == 'blue' || $color == 'red' || $color == 'green') {
    //do something
}
```

There are several other options. Using `switch` operator:

```
switch ($color) {
    case 'blue':
    case 'red':
    case 'green':
        //do something
}
```

Or more complex using [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function:

```
$colors = array('blue', 'red', 'green');
if (in_array($color, $colors)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks ;). Also, if I had around 10 different colors, which method would be the quickest/least server dependent to use?

Comment: Conditional operators (i.e. `if` and `switch`) are definitely the fastest but for large number of comparisons (especially for one variable) not very convenient. However for modern computers `in_array` method will be both fast and good looking.

Answer (score 2):

Use a switch-statement.

```
switch($color)
{
    case "blue":
        // do blue stuff
        break;
    case "yellow":
        // do yellow stuff
        break;
    case "red":
        // do red stuff
        break;
    default:
        // if everything else fails...
}
```

In case you want to do the same thing on all colors, just use the `||` (boolean or) operator.

```
if ($color == "blue" || $color == "red" || $color == "yellow")
{
     // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with `preg_match` on this one. This might be overkill, but I'm sure it's very fast!

```
$color = "blue";
$pattern = "/^red|blue|yellow$/";
if ( preg_match($pattern,$color) ) { 
    // Do something nice here!
}
```